# midnight commander subshell - sharing a history file with the shell mc was started from

Tags: linux, shell, midnight-commander

I am looking for a way to make `midnight commander` share its subshell history with the parent shell. To be more specific, when I start `mc`, open its subshell using <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> and subsequently invoke a command in the subshell, this command is not available in the outer shell history after exiting `mc`. Is there a way to share the history between the two shells? I start `mc` from `bash`, if that's relevant. Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This could be done with the following command (before starting mc):

```
export PROMPT_COMMAND="history -a; history -r"
```

If you would like to make it permanent, then you should add it to your `~/.bashrc`. But it will make all shell history global, which is not the best. If you don't want this side effect, then the following line should be added instead of the above one:

```
alias mc='PROMPT_COMMAND="history -a; history -r" mc; history -r'
```

Explanation:

`PROMPT_COMMAND` is executed just before bash displays a prompt. Further reading [here](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x264.html).

`history` should be called with append parameter, and after that with read parameter. Further reading [here](http://ss64.com/bash/history.html).

Comment: nice one, works great.

Answer (score 4):

For some reason, the `PROMPT_COMMAND` solution in an `mc` alias, as suggested by user szkj, didn't work correctly for me. While it did preserve commands executed in the MC subshell, commands entered before starting MC were lost after exiting.

Finally, I use the following in `~/.bashrc`, without an `mc` alias. It seems to work fine despite the fact that `mc` overwrites `$PROMPT_COMMAND`.

```
export HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth
shopt -s histappend
export PROMPT_COMMAND="history -a; history -c; history -r; $PROMPT_COMMAND"
```

This is what I get:

```
# echo "1: before starting MC. PROMPT_COMMAND=$PROMPT_COMMAND"
1: before starting MC. PROMPT_COMMAND=history -a; history -c; history -r; 

# mc

# echo "2: Inside MC. PROMPT_COMMAND=$PROMPT_COMMAND"
2: Inside MC. PROMPT_COMMAND=pwd>&8;kill -STOP $$

# history | tail -3
 3038 echo "1: before starting MC. PROMPT_COMMAND=$PROMPT_COMMAND"
 3039 echo "2: Inside MC. PROMPT_COMMAND=$PROMPT_COMMAND"
 3040 history | tail -3

# echo "3: Going to exit MC with F10."
3: Going to exit MC with F10.

# echo "4: Back in Bash after MC"
4: Back in Bash after MC

# history | tail -7
 3038 echo "1: before starting MC. PROMPT_COMMAND=$PROMPT_COMMAND"
 3039 echo "2: Inside MC. PROMPT_COMMAND=$PROMPT_COMMAND"
 3040 history | tail -3
 3041 echo "3: Going to exit MC with F10."
 3042 mc
 3043 echo "4: Back in Bash after MC"
 3044 history | tail -7
```

My system is:

```
# cat /etc/debian_version 
8.1

# bash --version | head -1
GNU bash, version 4.3.30(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

# mc --version | head -1
GNU Midnight Commander 4.8.13

# uname -a
Linux afnet 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.7-ckt11-1+deb8u3 (2015-08-04) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: ```despite the fact that mc overwrites $PROMPT_COMMAND``` actually it doesn't overwrite since 4.8.14.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly because my yet low reputation I can not comment the previous post(s) but I really would like to share that it seems for me @mivk 's solution works fine even in now *('22)*, with ZSH also using the following 'mutation':

```
export HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth
#shopt -s histappend # For BASH
setopt APPEND_HISTORY # For ZSH
export PROMPT_COMMAND="history -a; history -c; history -r; $PROMPT_COMMAND"
```